# CSS not being applied to radio buttons

Tags: html, css

As part of form validation, this is my attempt to make radio buttons that haven't been checked yet turn red -

```css
input[type="radio"].error
{
 border: 2px red inset;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<label>task:</label>
<span id="Tasks">
<input type="radio" name="Task" id="backup" class="error" value="backup"/>
<label for="backup" class="rblabel">backup</label>
<input type="radio" name="Task" id="retire" class="error" value="retire"/>
<label for="retire" class="rblabel">retire</label>
<input type="radio" name="Task" id="unretire" class="error" value="unretire"/><label for="unretire" class="rblabel">unretire</label>
</span>
```

Unfortunately, the styles specified in the CSS are not being applied to the HTML.  Why not?

Comment: Yes.  The answer was within that post.  `outline: 2px red inset;` rather than `border: 2px red inset;` fixed it.

Comment: Another option to achieve this (which is more flexible than trying to style the built-in radio box) is to use a web font lib like Fontawesome. Here is a working example https://jsfiddle.net/6j3esj0v/

Comment: Use outline instead border, here is working jsfiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/78nsvp6p/